# Simulation from cdf

Tags: simulation

Give a method for simulating from

> $$F(x) =\left\{\matrix{ \frac{(1-e^{-2x}+2x)}{3},& 0 < x < 1\cr
> \frac{3-e^{-2x}}{3}, & 1 < x < ∞}\right.$$

(Work out the pdf, and try to write it as a mixture, with one of the components being an $Exp(λ)$ pdf )

Can someone help me here? What should I do after I differentiate the respective $F(x)$ and get $f(x)$.

Comment: Is this homework? What did you try?

Comment: A sample question for my finals. I combined the two pdfs obtained  from F'(x) and didn't know how to continue after that.

Comment: How come we do not see what you did to follow the indication to "Work out the pdf, and try to write it as a mixture, with one of the components being an Exp(λ) pdf"?

Answer (score 0):

First differentiate $F$ to get the density function $f(x)$, then observe that the density can be writtes as
$$
     f(x) = \frac23 e^{-2x} + \frac23I(0<x<1).
$$
That is a mixture between an exponential distribution (with mean $1/2$) and a uniform distribution on the unit interval, and can be simulated as such.